# CSS code appearing on web page unrendered

Tags: html, css

so I'm a beginner working on a simple webpage and I'm not sure why there is css code appearing on the screen next to the first h1 element, "THINGS I LOVE TO DO". style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;" is not rendering.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Project 1 </title>
    </head>
    <body style="text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif">
        <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="A picture of a coding concept" style= "width: 100%;"> 
        <h1>3 style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;"> THINGS I LOVE TO DO... </h1>
        <p> What do you like to do for fun? Here's a list of 3 things that I love doing in my spare time:</p>
        <img src="images/image_2.jpg" style= "width: 50%;">
        <h2>1. Coding</h2>
        <p> Coding is the art of giving instructions to a computer. This page was created using HTML and CSS code.</p>
        <img src="images/image 3.jpg" style="width: 50%;">
        <h2>2.Listening to Music</h2>
        <p> It helps me relax and sometimes, focus</p>
        <img src="images/image 4.jpg" style="width:50%;">
        <h2> Drinking Coffee</h2>
        <p>I love a nice smooth roasted blend to wake me up in the morning!</p>
        <p>...and here's a fun fact! I did all three of these things while making this web page. Hope you like it!</p>
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Style should be inside the tag as below:

```
<h1 style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;"> 3 THINGS I LOVE TO DO... </h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Only problem is here

```
 <h1>3 style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;"> THINGS I LOVE TO DO... </h1>
```

I corrected it adding `css` properties inside the `h1` element

```
<h1 style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;">3 THINGS I LOVE TO DO... </h1>
```

you have used `css` properties outside the `h1` element.
follow some tutorial if you don't have an idea about CSS https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp

```html
<body style="text-align: center; font-family: sans-serif;">

                <img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="A picture of a coding concept" style= "width: 100%;"> 
                <h1 style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;">3 THINGS I LOVE TO DO... </h1>
                <p> What do you like to do for fun? Here's a list of 3 things that I love doing in my spare time:</p>
                <img src="images/image_2.jpg" style= "width: 50%;">
                <h2>1. Coding</h2>
                <p> Coding is the art of giving instructions to a computer. This page was created using HTML and CSS code.</p>
                <img src="images/image 3.jpg" style="width: 50%;">
                <h2>2.Listening to Music</h2>
                <p> It helps me relax and sometimes, focus</p>
                <img src="images/image 4.jpg" style="width:50%;">
                <h2> Drinking Coffee</h2>
                <p>I love a nice smooth roasted blend to wake me up in the morning!</p>
                <p>...and here's a fun fact! I did all three of these things while making this web page. Hope you like it!</p>

    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've placed the `style` tag outside of tag name which renders in the HTML. You just have to place the `style` tag before the end of the HTML tag of `h1`

```
<h1 **place style here** >
```

It should be

```
<h1 style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;"> THINGS I LOVE TO DO... </h1>
```

instead of

```
<h1>3 style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;"> THINGS I LOVE TO DO... </h1>
```

```html
<img src="images/banner.jpg" alt="A picture of a coding concept" style="width: 100%;">
<h1 style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;"> THINGS I LOVE TO DO... </h1>
<p> What do you like to do for fun? Here's a list of 3 things that I love doing in my spare time:</p>
<img src="images/image_2.jpg" style="width: 50%;">
<h2>1. Coding</h2>
<p> Coding is the art of giving instructions to a computer. This page was created using HTML and CSS code.</p>
<img src="images/image 3.jpg" style="width: 50%;">
<h2>2.Listening to Music</h2>
<p> It helps me relax and sometimes, focus</p>
<img src="images/image 4.jpg" style="width:50%;">
<h2> Drinking Coffee</h2>
<p>I love a nice smooth roasted blend to wake me up in the morning!</p>
<p>...and here's a fun fact! I did all three of these things while making this web page. Hope you like it!</p>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please write correct code.

`<h1>3 style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;"> THINGS I LOVE TO DO... </h1>`
This statement is wrong.
Use below statement: `<h1 style="font-family: Arial Black, sans-serif;"> THINGS I LOVE TO DO... </h1>`